# How do i make text with background become visible out of block with overflow:hidden:?

Tags: html, css

My text has a background as an icon, so I need half of icon be visible out of block, but `overflow:hidden;` won't allow me to, I tried giving `text-overflow:visible;` but I don't know too much about `css` `Html`, here's a little example

```css
.example{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  height: 277px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #000;
 }

.example-title{
  position:absolute;
  top: -6%;
  left: 63%;
  background:#0d3351;
  padding: 35px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
 <span class="example-title">
       Visible
 </span>
</div>
```

Here is screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKrge.jpg)

Comment: do you have an image of what you tried to do

Comment: I have an image(pr screenshot), how do i show it?

Comment: when you edit question you have button to add image

Comment: Added an image, don't know if it would help

Comment: and why you need overflow:hidden? simply remove it

Comment: if i remove it my img will fit all width of monitor and im making mobile first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element with `position: absolute` could be visibile outside of its parent with `overflow: hidden` only if the parent does not have a `position` rule, so I think that you'll need a common parent element with `position: relative` rule and no `position` rule on the `.example` element.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}

.example{
  overflow:hidden;
  height: 277px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #000;
 }

.example-title{
  position:absolute;
  top: -6%;
  left: 63%;
  background:#0d3351;
  padding: 35px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="example">
    <span class="example-title">
      Visible
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: IT WORKED, you're genius thank you, saved my time and live :D